# Hover menu's max-width being ignored when parent has a relative positioning

Tags: css, css-position

Absolutely positioned element's width constrained when parent is relative

I have a navbar that has a menu on hover. The menu will contain  tags and the length of the text in the  tags will vary.

I want the menu to have a minimum and maxmium width child div has to have min-width/max-width set to. But no matter what the width of the menu is constrained to the min-width point.

Is it possible to make the child div ignore the width of the parent, while still keeping it a child (I cannot move this out of the parent, which I know would be an easy solution)?

here is an example of the behavior I am encountering: https://codepen.io/vee1234/pen/omQxWP

```css
.navBar {
  background-color: #222;
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navItem {
  color: #a1a1a1;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 100%;
  top: 20%;
}

.menu div a {
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.navItem:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navBar">
    <div class="navItem">
      <div>Nav Menu Trigger</div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="link">
          <a>string of any length</a>
          <a>string of any length - but this one is super long</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navItem">
      <div>Nav Menu Trigger</div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="link">
          <a>string of any length</a>
          <a>string of any length - but this one is super long</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="navItem">
      <div>Nav Menu Trigger</div>
      <div className="menu">
        <div className="link">
          <a>string of any length</a>
          <a>string of any length - but this one is super long</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to you `.link a` as it is bleeding outside the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick is to make the relative element to be bigger by adding some `padding-right` that will not affect how text goes inside but will be counted in the width calculation of the absolute element. Then simply color only the part you want. You may also add negative margin to rectify the padding added.

```css
.menu {
  width:50px;
  padding-right:500px;
  margin-right:-500px;
  background:#000 content-box;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  color:#fff;
}

.menu div{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50px;
  background:blue;
  min-width:200px;
  max-width:500px;
}
.menu div a {
  border:1px solid;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
 some text here
  <div>
    <a>some text here</a>
    <a>some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here</a>
    <a>some text here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting!!! this is getting close but not sure about the case when there is more than one navitem/menu. See example here https://codepen.io/vee1234/pen/omQxWP... On hover, other nav items are pushed down with the menu appearing.

Comment: @user10782250 used the wrong padding, check the update ... it should be right

Comment: @user10782250 the element should be position:absolute in your code (the one where you applied the css)

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning takes the element out of where it actually sits in the DOM and positions it where you tell it to. Because of this, the element looses references to parent elements that would help determine the width.  You will need to set the width explicitly.

Comment: Part of the design dictates a flexible width of the menu - there's no way to achieve that?

Comment: Not if it has to be absolute position.